# mysql view with group by - performance problem

Tags: mysql, performance, select, view

I have a table which collects data for web pages performance. There are multiple machines, testing multiple sites in 10 minutes intervals, so currently I have about 700 000 rows (920 MB) with +/- 50 000 new rows daily.

Table source:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE TABLE `http_perf_raw_log` (
  `run_dt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataset` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `runner` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `machine` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `called_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `method` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `http_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `header_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filetime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssl_verify_result` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `redirect_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namelookup_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connect_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pretransfer_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttransfer_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `redirect_time` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_upload` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size_download` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed_download` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed_upload` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `download_content_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upload_content_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certinfo` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_header` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `return_content` varchar(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `return_headers` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `run_dt_idx` (`run_dt`),
  KEY `dataset_idx` (`dataset`),
  KEY `runner_idx` (`runner`),
  KEY `site_idx` (`site`),
  KEY `machine_idx` (`machine`),
  KEY `total_time_idx` (`total_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For aggregating stats (with 1 hour resolution), I created a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW http_perf_stats (dataset, runner, site, machine, day, hour, calls, total_time, namelookup_time, connect_time, pretransfer_time, starttransfer_time, size_download) AS 
SELECT dataset,  runner, site, machine,
 DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day,
 DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%k') AS hour,
 COUNT(*) AS calls,
 SUM(total_time),
 SUM(namelookup_time), 
 SUM(connect_time),
 SUM(pretransfer_time), 
 SUM(starttransfer_time), 
 SUM(size_download)
FROM http_perf_raw_log GROUP BY runner, site, machine, day, hour ORDER BY `day` DESC
```

**But the performance of VIEW (and underlying SELECT) is terrible - takes about 4 seconds.**

So, my questions:

**1. Is using GROUP BY in a VIEW good idea at all? And if not, what is better alternative?**

**2. Is there ( I imagine yes, I am not SQL expert :/) a way to optimize this SELECT (changing query or structure of http_perf_raw_log)?**

Comment: Retrieving approximately all 920 MB of data without a limit is acceptable in 4 seconds. Anyway please post the EXPLAIN EXTENDED and run a profiler on the query itself (without view), and post back the findings.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it might be a good idea to only create statistics periodically (once per hour for example).

I'd do that as follows. Run the following code once to create a table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE http_perf_stats AS 
SELECT dataset,  runner, site, machine,
 DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day,
 DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%k') AS hour,
 COUNT(*) AS calls,
 SUM(total_time),
 SUM(namelookup_time), 
 SUM(connect_time),
 SUM(pretransfer_time), 
 SUM(starttransfer_time), 
 SUM(size_download)
FROM http_perf_raw_log 
GROUP BY runner, site, machine, day, hour 
ORDER BY `day` DESC
```

Make some modifications like changing field types, default values, adding a primary key, and perhaps add some indexes so that you can access and query this table in a fast way.

From then on, update the table like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

    DELETE FROM http_perf_stats;

    INSERT INTO TABLE 
      SELECT dataset,  runner, site, machine,
        DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day,
        DATE_FORMAT(run_dt, '%k') AS hour,
        COUNT(*) AS calls,
        SUM(total_time),
        SUM(namelookup_time), 
        SUM(connect_time),
        SUM(pretransfer_time), 
        SUM(starttransfer_time), 
        SUM(size_download)
      FROM http_perf_raw_log 
      GROUP BY runner, site, machine, day, hour 
      ORDER BY `day` DESC;

COMMIT;
```

Several ways to do this:

- Create a MySQL event (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) (that's how I would do it)
- Create a cron job (unix-flavoured systems) or window scheduler task
- Do a "lazy" update. When somebody requests this list, run the code above if the last time it was ran was longer than x minutes/hours ago. That way it works more like a cache. Slow on the first request, fast after. But you won't slow the server down unless somebody is interested in this.

Comment: I believe the transaction will not work. TRUNCATE cannot be rolled back. It would be safer to DROP and CREATE the table.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle: Good point: truncate causes an implicit commit. I think your proposed solution won't work as expected on innodb tables though. The point of the transaction was to ensure that other sessions dont see any empty table, but innodb tables become visible straight away (before the insert!). The simplest workaround here is probably to just `delete` instead of truncate. This case was about a table with aggregated data, and it would be called once per hour, so the performance gains of a drop+create would be negligable I guess.

Comment: Updated `truncate` to `delete`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `GROUP BY` from the VIEW and use it in the `SELECT` that calls the `VIEW`.

Comment: Although this is feasible, didn't seems like the smart way to do things. My system are using view extensively, and if just one SQL will be in the back-end will make things ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The view is just another SELECT query, but abstracted away to make it easier querying the resultset. If the underlying SELECT is slow, so is the view. Reading through and summing together 1 GB of data in four seconds doesn't sound slow at all to me.